# When including a template in another template, from an ansible role, what is the path?

Tags: kubernetes, ansible, jinja2

I am attempting to use templates to seed configurations for apps in an ansible role. The role will configure some related services.

Template 1 - `logging_config.json.j2`

```
{
  "logger_type": "foo_bar",
  "logger_host": "https://fo_host",
  "logger_token": "{{ secret_vault_logger_token }}"
}
```

Template 2 - `app1_config.json.j2`

```
{
  "api_url_foo": "{{ app1_foo_api_url }}",
  "logger": {% include "logging_config.json.j2" %}
}
```

Template 3 - `xapp2_config.json.j2`x

```
{
  "port": {{ app2_port }},
  "logger": {% include "logging_config.json.j2" %}
}
```

These are in a role - say `roles/my_apps/templates`. The role names templates `app2_config.json.j2` or `app1_config.json.j2` using the k8s module.

I always see this:

```
fatal: [k8s-non-devops]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "TemplateNotFound: logging_config.json.j2"
}
```

In that path I have tried: `templates/logging_config.json.j2`, `myapps/templates/logging_config.json.j2`, `roles/myapps/templates/logging_config.json.j2`.

The variables `template_path` and `template_fullpath` are undefined.

Where is it?

Answer (score 0):

In this instance, the j2 `{% include %}` syntax won't work. The paths don't appear to make sense. However, the ansible lookup plugin will do the job:

```
{
  "port": {{ app2_port }},
  "logger": {{ lookup('template', 'logging_config.json.j2' ) }}
}
```

This however come with a slight cost, ansible seems to recognise and alter the json, turning double quotes into single quotes and making it invalid. So if the config is json, you need to add | to_json:

```
{
  "port": {{ app2_port }},
  "logger": {{ lookup('template', 'logging_config.json.j2' ) | to_json }}
}
```